# Declaring a Default Option in custom style

Tags: package-writing, package-options

I'd like to create a style file that lets me choose between two versions of a document, one that contains identifying information and one that does not---is "suitable for blind review".

My idea is to enclose the identifying information in the argument \full{...}, the alternative for blind review in \blind{...}, and then select via an option in the style file which of these to print. Here's the minimal style file and a MWE of a corresponding .tex file.

Style file:

```
\ProvidesPackage{blinding}

\DeclareOption{blind}{%
%%% Code to print blinded version
%
% This code and the next option ("Full") are designed so that the
% source code contains alternatives for identifying
% information. Identifying information is enclosed in \full{...},
% blinded alternative information is enclosed in \blind{...}.
 \newcommand{\blind}[1]{#1}
 \newcommand{\full}[1]{}
}

\DeclareOption{full}{%
%%% Code to print the full version, including identifying information
\newcommand{\blind}[1]{}
\newcommand{\full}[1]{#1}
}

% Sets the default option to "full". (????)
\ExecuteOptions{full}

\ProcessOptions \relax
```

The idea is that when the "full" option is called, all of the material in     `\blind{...}` is simply skipped, and *mutatis mutandis* for the "blind" option. And the simple MWE is this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blinding}

\begin{document}
Some regular materials

\full{something in the full version}

\blind{something blinded}
\end{document}
```

The options work exactly as I want them to when I call them explicitly from within the `.tex` document and if the `.sty` file doesn't have the `\ExecuteOptions` command. The only problem is that I don't know how to make "full" the default in such a way that I can override

The end result I'm shooting for is this behavior:

- No option declared by author: print full version
- "full" option declared by author: print full version
- "blind" option declared by author: print blind version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, that the `full` option in your example is executed first and then the options are evaluated. Because of that, the `\newcommand{...}[1]{...}` doesn't work in the blind option. Instead you should use `\renewcommand`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{blinding}

\DeclareOption{blind}{%
%%% Code to print blinded version
%
% This code and the next option ("Full") are designed so that the
% source code contains alternatives for identifying
% information. Identifying information is enclosed in \full{...},
% blinded alternative information is enclosed in \blind{...}.
 \renewcommand{\blind}[1]{#1}
 \renewcommand{\full}[1]{}
}

\DeclareOption{full}{%
%%% Code to print the full version, including identifying information
\newcommand{\blind}[1]{}
\newcommand{\full}[1]{#1}
}

% Sets the default option to "full". (????)
\ExecuteOptions{full}

\ProcessOptions \relax
```

This should work when you use the `blind` option for the `blinding`-package.

EDIT: But the option `full` still doesn't work because the `\newcommand`s would be called twice. You might further change it to:

```
\ProvidesPackage{blinding}

\newcommand{\blind}[1]{}
\newcommand{\full}[1]{#1}

\DeclareOption{blind}{%
%%% Code to print blinded version
%
% This code and the next option ("Full") are designed so that the
% source code contains alternatives for identifying
% information. Identifying information is enclosed in \full{...},
% blinded alternative information is enclosed in \blind{...}.
 \renewcommand{\blind}[1]{#1}
 \renewcommand{\full}[1]{}
}

\DeclareOption{full}{%
%%% Code to print the full version, including identifying information
\renewcommand{\blind}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\full}[1]{#1}
}

\ProcessOptions \relax
```

This way the `full` option works (but is completely obsolete, since it doesn't change anything).